# How do I install WebKitGTK+ in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: gtk3, webkit

I want to build a web interface for my GTK+3 application but I have some problem in installing  WebKitGTK+. What are the dependencies that I need to install?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please could you add more information about the problem you're having?. May be you want to read this first: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the dependencies required for building WebKitGTK+3 :

- gst-plugins-base-1.6.3
- GTK+-2.24.29 or GTK+-3.18.7
- ICU-56.1
- libgudev-230
- libsecret-0.18.4
- libsoup-2.52.2
- libwebp-0.5.0
- Mesa-11.1.2
- Ruby-2.3.0
- SQLite-3.11.0
- Which-2.21